# ListView checkbox to visible or hide textbox in same row

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, checkbox

I have a listview with a column have checkbox and other column having textbox, with multiple row in the listview.
I want to set visible and hide property of textbox depending on checkbox checked and unchecked.
Its a WPF project using MVVM pattern and PRISM.
Please help, I am stuck.

```
<ListView Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PayFeeDetails}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="110" >
      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
             <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Width="30" Name="CommentCheckBox"/>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn Width="140">
      <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="GameName" Content="Game Name" />
       <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
             <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Balance}"/>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Balance}"/>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
   </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

Comment: Anything that your tried so far ?

Comment: giving name to checkbox and binding element name in the textbox along with using BooleanToVisibilityConverter. But it didnt work.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to set a property in your item been bound to as the state of the checkbox, and bind that property to your text box visibility using a bool to visibility converter.

Comment: what is `PayFeeDetails`?

Comment: 'PayFeeDetails' is property defined in the ViewModel which has been binded in the View.

Comment: Also fix up your XAML, what you have does not even compile. Where is the starting tag of GridView.

Comment: well, i realize that - what I meant was, can you show the implementation of that list and the class it contains?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a binding to the Visibility of second Gridview Grid.
Now on Gridview1 itemclick create a INotify property change and update that particular item's Grid Visibility from the collection thats been set as source in second grid.

Comment: I am new to WPF ,MVVM and PRISM. 
In this project I am using PRISM so the model defined is inheriting BindableBase, which has inbuild INotify property.

Comment: If you are using Prism then thats good as you wont have to worry about Inotify property. Now you would need to add a new variable which is of Visibility type and this will be bindable to the Grid of second Gridview. when initially populating set it to Visibility.Collapsed.
 Now when an item is clicked in first Gridview you would need to update the Collection of Second Gridview to Visibility.Visible

Answer (score 0):

I would go this route

1) Create an object with a property that lets me know I can edit.

```
public class  ItemToBindTo:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Fields
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private bool _canEdit;
    private string _description;
    private string _balance;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public bool CanEdit
    {
        get
        {
            return _canEdit;
        }
        set
        {
            _canEdit = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("CanEdit");
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _description;
        }
        set
        {
            _description = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }

    public string Balance
    {
        get
        {
            return _balance;
        }
        set
        {
            _balance = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("Balance");
        }
    }
    #endregion 
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

2) I will create converters for visibility

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var val = value as bool? ;
        return val.HasValue && val.Value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class InvertedBoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var val = value as bool?;
        return !(val.HasValue && val.Value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I will have my converters as static resources

```
     <sigColor:InvertedBoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InvertedBoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
    <sigColor:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

And this will be your new xaml

```
<ListView Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PayFeeDetails}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="110" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                            <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Width="30" Name="CommentCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding CanEdit, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn >
                <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="GameName" Content="Game Name" />
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Balance}" Visibility="{Binding CanEdit, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Balance}" Visibility="{Binding CanEdit, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```